# Pass DHCP user class in netplan

Tags: networking, dhcp, systemd-networkd, netplan

Is it possible to pass a DHCP option 77 and/or DHCPv6 option 15 in netplan using the networkd backend. Currently networkd supports passing DHCP option 77 and I believe there is work on adding the ability to pass custom DHCPv6 options, however I don't know how to setup netplan to support these configuration options.

I use Ubuntu and in the past I have always called dhclient manually from ifupdown. This gives me the most control over the DHCP workflow. I would have something like this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 manual
    post-up dhclient -6 -1 -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.$IFACE.conf $IFACE
    pre-down dhclient -r -6 -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.$IFACE.conf $IFACE
iface eth0 inet manual
    post-up dhclient -i -1 -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.$IFACE.conf $IFACE
    pre-down dhclient -r -i -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.$IFACE.conf $IFACE
```

This allows me to have a configuration files with specific DHCP settings for each interface and in the dhcp configuration file I could specify DHCP options to send to the server:

```
option         dhcp6.user-class code 15 = text;

timeout        60;
retry          300;
select-timeout 5;
reboot         10;
initial-delay  1;

interface "eth0" {
    send       dhcp6.user-class "cmp cloud mgmt";
    send       user-class "cmp cloud mgmt";
    send       fqdn.fqdn "bllcloudcmp01-mgmt.harmonywave.cloud.";
    send       fqdn.server-update on;
    request    subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu, ntp-servers;
}
```

Since option 77 is defined by default in dhclient all I had to do was define option 15 in the dhcp6 user space and I could pass both.

Anybody know how to translate the above ifupdown configuration into netplan?